# Partial View with variable model type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, generic-type-argument

Update from Travis Answer :

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id{get;set;}
    string Name{get;set;}
}
public class Vehicule:IEntity
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
public class Sector:IEntity
{
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

and this model for the main View :

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public Vehicule Vehicule{ get; set; }
    public Sector Sector{ get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to implement a form for each entity (It will be a modal form but it's not the point).
It will be more complex, but for the exemple it's just :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Name)
//etc...
```

I'm trying to implement the interface with generic type but I don't really understand how to do, especially generic type.

Now I have `@model GenericViewModel<IEntity>` in my partial view and `MainViewModel` in my view.

How to pass the model to partial view with the generic type?

`@Html.RenderPartial("_PartialView",????)`

I think there is something missing in `MainViewModel` but I tried a lot of things without success.

It would be very helpful if you could tell me what I'm missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an interface to expose properties or behaviors across different types.

```
public interface IEntity
{
    string PropertyA;
    string PropertyB;
    string PropertyC;
}
```

Then have each entity inherit this interface

```
public class Entity1 : IEntity { ... }
public class Entity2 : IEntity { ... }
public class Entity3 : IEntity { ... }
```

And now in your view you can expose the interface properties to the entities

```
@model GenericModelType<IEntity>
```